# Ubuntu password reset question unable to shutdown 12.04

Tags: password, shutdown, reboot

So basically my father passed away has Ubuntu on a Lenovo t61. I have no idea what his password was and I really want to be able to access all the stuff on his computer.

I have done the following with no success.

1.I changed the password by editing 'ro quiet splash $vt handoff' to 'rw init=/bin/bash'
2.I typed in root@(none) passwd root 
3. changed the password successfully

but when I try to reboot I get a message that says 'unable to shutdown'

I just need to get the files and whatnot off of this computer. PLease help!

Thank you
scott

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

Usually what I do is boot the machine from a Live Disc (from USB) then click the 'Try Ubuntu' option.

### Explained

Once the system is running I then mount the primary machine to my live disc giving you full root access to the machine when you `sudo su` (as the trial doesn't require a password).

(Assuming you're root) However you could replace your dads password hash by:

1. Running `passwd` which will prompt you for a new password;
2. Once set `cat /etc/shadow | grep 'ubuntu'` will display you the password hash;
3. You need to mount the primary hard disk in order to forcefully write the new password;

Mounting the disk you will need to work out which disk is the primary; usually that's /dev/sda1.  To list the partition table you will need to run the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

You'll seesomething like:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    39845887    19921920   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        39847934    41940991     1046529    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        39847936    41940991     1046528   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

The importance here is to know you need `Linux` under `System` (not swap - that's something different.)

Then you should:

1. Change directory to establish the mount: `cd /mnt`;
2. Create a directory: `sudo mkdir test`;
3. You can mount your primary disk via `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/test`;

Now you should be able to access your dads machine via: `cd /mnt/test/`.

Going back to my point about replacing a root password, you could copy the password hash from the initial step and paste it into `/mnt/test/etc/.shadow` next to the root user.

Hope this helps.